# How to prove Mean Squarred Error (MSE)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-algebra, mse

I would like to prove this equation of Mean Squared Error (MSE):

[image]

- *m* is the number of training instances.
- *X* is a m × n matrix containing all the feature values (excluding
  labels) of all instances in the dataset.
- *X*^*T* is the transpose of matrix X.
- *w* is the model’s parameter vector, containing the bias term w0 and the feature weights w1 to wn.
- *y* is the vector of target values containing y(1) to y(m) values (training instances).

The above function is the gradient of the minimum squared error loss function:

[image]

where,

- *m* is the number of training instances.
- *hw* is the hypothesis function, using the model parameters w.
- *x(i)* is a n × 1 vector of all the feature values (excluding the label) of the i-th instance in the dataset, and *y(i)* is its label (the desired output for this instance)

I would really appreciate any clue for a start at least or any relevant link where I could find more information.

Comment: I'm confident we can help, but please explain what all your symbols mean so we don't guess incorrectly.

Comment: @whuber Yes you are right..Let me update the question

Comment: Do you know matrix calculus? It's a straightforward result from that. Also, by your result, $h$ should be a linear function

Comment: @Firebug I am a totally newbie in mathematics. Since you wrote matrix calculus, I will search of it. However, I would really appreciate it if you provide more input on that.

Comment: No need to search for that, I'll try to provide a simpler answer. It's just that, if you knew it already it would be simpler :)

Comment: @BDEngineer Firebug's done a nice job outlining the mechanics of this solution (+1). If you're looking for broader treatments, we have several threads with additional resources: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+calculus

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you for the comment. I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's identify what we mean here:

$$\text{MSE}=\frac{1}{m}\sum (X_iW-Y_i)^2$$

And the gradient is a vector of partial derivatives:

$$\nabla_W\text{MSE}=\left[\frac{\partial \text{MSE}}{\partial W_j} \right]$$

$$\frac{\partial \text{MSE}}{\partial W_j}=
\frac{1}{m}\frac{\partial}{\partial W_j}\sum (X_iW-Y_i)^2=\\
\frac{1}{m}\sum 2(X_iW-Y_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial W_j}(X_iW-Y_i)
$$

Remember that $X_iW = \sum_k x_{ik}W_{k}$
This last derivative is then simply:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_j}(X_iW-Y_i) = \frac{\partial}{\partial W_j}(\sum_k x_{ik}W_{k}-Y_i)=x_{ij}$$

Then, recognizing that the resulting sum is a vector product:

$$\frac{\partial \text{MSE}}{\partial W_j}=
\frac{1}{m}\sum 2(X_iW-Y_i)x_{ij} = \frac{2}{m} x_j^T(XW-Y)
$$

Where $x_j$ is the $j$-th column of $X$

Then reorganizing into the columns of the gradient we can recognize that it's a matrix product, arriving at the result:

$$\nabla_W\text{MSE}=\left[\frac{2}{m} x_j^T(XW-Y) \right]_j = \frac{2}{m}X^T(XW-Y)$$

---

Using matrix calculus:

$$\text{MSE}=\frac{1}{m}\epsilon^T\epsilon =\frac{1}{m} (XW-Y)^T(XW-Y)$$

$$\frac{\partial \text{MSE}}{\partial W}=
\frac{1}{m} \frac{\partial}{\partial W}(XW-Y)^T(XW-Y)=\\
\frac{1}{m} \left(\frac{\partial (XW-Y)^T}{\partial W}(XW-Y) + \left((XW-Y)^T\frac{\partial (XW-Y)}{\partial W}\right)^T\right)=\\
\frac{1}{m} \left(X^T(WX-Y) + ((WX-Y)^TX)^T\right) = \frac{2}{m} X^T(WX-Y)$$